# Assembly: Changing character in string

Tags: string, assembly, char

I'm trying to change a string of numbers like '00000000$', and then print the string to a file.

For example when I use something like this:

```
nr  db '00000000$'  


asdf PROC near

mov bx, offset nr
add bx, 7
mov [bx], '0'
dec bx
mov [bx], '4'
dec bx
mov [bx], '0'
dec bx
mov [bx], '3'
dec bx
mov [bx], '0'
dec bx
mov [bx], '2'
dec bx
mov [bx], '0'
dec bx
mov [bx], '1'
ret

asdf ENDP
```

and then print it to file with:

```
mov bx, FHandle
mov cx, 8
mov ah, 40h
int 21h
```

I get a file with '2' and 7 spaces printed after it.
I'm not sure if I'm doing the printing wrong, or if I'm changing the string wrong.

Comment: @ooga I edited it a bit, but I'm not really sure what else I could add.

Comment: Well then I would suggest that whatever is doing the output is converting `'0'` to space. Because if your code works right with every other character you put there, then it's likely also putting the "0" characters there as well. Perhaps you should use a debugger, single-step the code, and *look at the memory*.

Comment: @JimMischel Thing is, if I print out a string '00000000' without changing it, it works fine, but even if I change a zero in '00000000' the zeroes that I change become spaces.

Comment: @JimMischel "Perhaps you should use a debugger, single-step the code, and look at the memory." I only recently started assembly and I honestly don't have even the slightest clue how to do these things.

Comment: And if you change your string to `'10203040'`, does it change the 0's to spaces, and output the 1, 2, 3, and 4? It's highly likely that the problem is in your output function.

Comment: @JimMischel Ok, this completely confused me. when I try to change it to '10203040' It prints out '2' and then 7 spaces. My output function is just an int 21h with ah being 40h (print to file).

Comment: I can't help if you don't show the code. It's best if you can cut it down to a short and complete sample that illustrates the problem. However, you should note that with INT 21h, function 40, you need to put the number of bytes to write in the CX register. It doesn't terminate with the '$' character like function 9 does. See http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah40

Comment: @JimMischel Edited the question, I do specify how many bytes to print in cx, but don't really know what's wrong with the program. I assumed earlier that it was something else, but now I'm completely stunned.

Comment: you must tag the correct architecture here

Comment: You don't show `mov dx, offset nr` before you write to file. Are you setting up `ds` in the beginning?

Comment: And your code is doing *nothing else* between the call to your `asdf` proc and the output? You're *certain* of that? Because what you're describing doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `destination index` (`rdi` x86_64, `edi` x86) to write the character value into your variable. It can be done a number of different ways, but this is straight forward. The following changes all `1's` to `0's` as well as changing the space to `0`. (to limit just to the ones, change the loop counter `rcx` to `8`:

```
section .data

    dnln db 0xa,0xa
    bfield db '11111111 '

section .bss

section .text
                global _start

        _start:

                mov     rdi, bfield         ; put address of bfield in rdi
                mov     cx, 9               ; set loop counter to 9

        _fill:                              ; loop label for fill
                mov     [rdi], byte '0'     ; move '0' into address
                inc     rdi                 ; increment address
                loop    _fill               ; loop

                mov     rax, 1              ; print bfield
                mov     rdi, 1
                mov     rsi, bfield
                mov     rdx, 9
                syscall

                mov     rax, 1              ; print 2 newlines
                mov     rdi, 1
                mov     rsi, dnln
                mov     rdx, 2
                syscall

        exit:
                xor     rdi, rdi
                mov     rax, 0x3c
                syscall
```

**build/link:**

```
nasm -f elf64 -o zero_64.o zero_64.asm
ld  -o ./bin/zero_64 zero_64.o
```

**output:**

```
$./bin/zero_64
000000000
```

**Note:** this answers the question as it was originally posted. While writing to a file was not part of your original question, you can simply create a file with the `__NR_creat` call (`85` x86_64 or `8` x86) with the file descriptor returned to (rax/eax). Drop a comment if you are still having difficulty.

Comment: If  you have a downvote, please have the integrity to explain your downvote. I was surprised to see the question had completely changed following posting the answer.

Comment: I'm not downvoting but I think the OP isn't using x86_64

Comment: The OP is obviously using MASM/TASM for MS-DOS. An answer with NASM for Linux64 could be estimated as trolling.